# Haskell compiler magic: what requires a special treatment from the compiler?

Tags: haskell, ghc

When trying to learn Haskell, one of the difficulties that arise is the ability when something requires special magic from the compiler.  One exemple that comes in mind is the `seq` function which can't be defined i.e. you can't make a `seq2` function behaving exactly as the built-in `seq`. Consequently, when teaching someone about `seq`, you need to mention that `seq` is special because it's a special symbol for the compiler.

Another example would be the `do`-notation which only works with instances of the `Monad` class.

Sometimes, it's not always obvious. For instance, continuations. Does the compiler knows about `Control.Monad.Cont` or is it plain old Haskell that you could have invented yourself? In this case, I think nothing special is required from the compiler even if continuations are a very strange kind of beast.

Language extensions set aside, what other compiler magic Haskell learners should be aware of?

Comment: Stating the obvious: anything `IO` falls under "magic" for any reasonable definition of "magic": https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/450baq/is_it_just_me_or_does_ios_definition_give_you_the/. Also the `ST` monad, which is probably even more magic.

Comment: What about STM? And stream fusion?

Comment: yeah those too, but STM gets its magic from IO, and steam fusion is rewrite rules, which is itself magic.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call stream fusion magic. You can create your own rewrite rules, so that is more a tool of the language than magic (in GHC extended Haskell at least). Also if things are indirectly, vicariously magic just because they use something else that's magic, then it seems like pretty much everything is magic because you generally ultimately end up at `IO`. Granted, `STM` probably falls a bit more on the magic side because it probably directly uses stuff like `State# RealWorld` internally at some point.

Comment: The things the GHC developers typically call "magic" are ones that get special treatment from the compiler. `Coercible` (defined as `data` and with its kind magically changed to `k -> k -> Constraint`) and `lazy` (which "magically" makes GHC consider a function lazy) are good examples.

Comment: I guess the answer is "a lot of stuff." Actually, given how concise Haskell's definition is, it might be easier to list what *isn't* magic (which is really what made Haskell magic in the first place :)).

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/compiler/basicTypes/MkId.hs#L121) for the part of the GHC source which defines primitive identifiers (i.e. functions). Perhaps the only surprising thing that is primitive is `($) :: (a -> b) -> (a -> b)`.

Comment: You can implement STM as normal user code. It all lives in the `IO` monad of course, but STM itself isn't particularly magic; the magic is in `MVar`, `forkIO`, et al.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nearly all the ghc primitives that cannot be implemented in userland are in the [ghc-prim](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim) package. (it even has a module called `GHC.Magic` there!)

So browsing it will give a good sense.

Note that you should *not* use this module in userland code unless you know exactly what you are doing. Most of the usable stuff from it is exported in downstream modules in `base`, sometimes in modified form. Those downstream locations and APIs are considered more stable, while `ghc-prim` makes no guarantees as to how it will act from version to version.

The GHC-specific stuff is reexported in [`GHC.Exts`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/GHC-Exts.html), but plenty of other things go into the Prelude (such as basic data types, as well as `seq`) or the concurrency libraries, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Polymorphic `seq` is definitely magic. You *can* implement `seq` for any *specific* type, but only the compiler can implement one function for *all* possible types [and avoid optimising it away even though it looks no-op].

Obviously the entire `IO` monad is deeply magic, as is everything to with concurrency and parallelism (`par`, `forkIO`, `MVar`), mutable storage, exception throwing and catching, querying the garbage collector and run-time stats, etc.

The `IO` monad can be considered a special case of the `ST` monad, which is also magic. (It allows truly mutable storage, which requires low-level stuff.)

The `State` monad, on the other hand, is completely ordinary user-level code that anybody can write. So is the `Cont` monad. So are the various exception / error monads.

Anything to do with syntax (do-blocks, list comprehensions) is hard-wired into the language definition. (Note, though, that some of these respond to `LANGUAGE RebindableSyntax`, which lets you change what functions it binds to.) Also the `deriving` stuff; the compiler "knows about" a handful of special classes and how to auto-generate instances for them. Deriving for `newtype` works for *any* class though. (It's just copying an instance from one type to another identical copy of that type.)

Arrays are hard-wired. Much like every other programming language.

All of the foreign function interface is clearly hard-wired.

STM *can* be implemented in user code (I've done it), but it's currently hard-wired. (I imagine this gives a significant performance benefit. I haven't tried actually measuring it.) But, conceptually, that's just an optimisation; you *can* implement it using the existing lower-level concurrency primitives.

Comment: "seq for any specific type" No, you can't do that for function type.